# Create datamodule instance multiple times for same form

Tags: delphi, firedac

Good morning, I have an MDI application which I have a search form with a grid (`frmCustomerSearch`) and a view form (`frmCustomerView`), these are both child MDI forms.

The search form can only be opened once but the view form multiple times

Search is connected to `dmCustomerSearch` and view to `dmCustomerView`, I create an instance of the `dmCustomerView` on the create of `frmCustomerView`, filter the query by parameter and then open the query as below.

```
  dmCustomerViewFrm := TdmCustomerViewFrm.create(self);
  dmCustomerViewFrm.fdqCustView.ParamByName('REF').Value := fAccountRef;
  dmCustomerViewFrm.fdqCustView.Open;

// Set dataModule to an empty string, prevents other forms using it.
  dmCustomerViewFrm.Name := '';
```

The form opens on the correct record and I can edit the record without an issue.... my issue is when I open more than one record, I can edit the last record opened but anything prior I get the following error:

> FDQCustView: Dataset not in edit or insert mode.

Is the new instance taking the original out of edit mode? or am I missing something?

Any advice greatly appreciated!

Comment: it seems like you design is bad. The use of global variables is biting you in the ass... You need a set of query components for each customer form. The only thing you can share is the database connection.

Comment: I have voted to close this q because you have not explained **exactly** what you are doing when the error occurs.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks @whosrdaddy, I'll take a look at removing the globals and trying that, MartynA, I am using the SaveRecord on a ActionList, essentially posting changes.

Comment: Well, your code to save changes should check that the dataset's State (TDataSetState) is dsInsert or dsEdit and only attempt to save if it is in one of those.  E.g. `if (DataSet.State in [dsInsert, dsEdit]) then  {save changes here} `

Comment: Thanks MartynA, but the issue is that it's trying to edit the incorrect dataset, based on the datamodule being created with a global form name, I'm trying to get to grips with creating one instance of the DM for every instance of the view frm.